# Persist another entity in preUpdate LifecycleCallback

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine, zend-framework2

I have this `User` entity

```
/**
 * User Entity.
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Application\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\EntityListeners({"Application\Listener\User"})
 */
class User extends Entity implements UserInterface, ProviderInterface
{
...

    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\Organization
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Organization")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="organization_id", referencedColumnName="organization_id")
     * })
     */
    protected $organization;

...
}
```

Wich uses the listener

```
namespace Application\Listener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;

class User
{

    public function preUpdate(\Application\Entity\User $user, PreUpdateEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        if ($eventArgs->hasChangedField('organization')) {
            $oldOrganization = $eventArgs->getOldValue('organization');

            if ($oldOrganization) {
                $oldOrganization->decreaseTotalMembers();
                $eventArgs->getEntityManager()->persist($oldOrganization);
            }

            $newOrganization = $eventArgs->getNewValue('organization');

            if ($newOrganization) {
                $newOrganization->increaseTotalMembers();
                $eventArgs->getEntityManager()->persist($newOrganization);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

So, as you can see, every single time a user change organization, I would like to decrease the number of members in the old organization and increase in the new organization.

So, in the controller when I create an organization I have:

```
public function createAction(){
...
   $this->getOrganizationService()->hydrateOrganization($organization, $data);

   $user = $organization->getAuthor();

   if (!$user->hasOrganization()) {
      $user->setOrganization($organization);
      $this->getUserService()->saveUser($user);
   }
 ...
}
```

So I expect that when save the user (persist + flush), the increasement in the total members of the organization is flushed as well but it does not occur.

Do you have any idea on why is it happending and how to solve it?

Comment: If the flush triggers the preupdate then there is no flush that writes your changes inside the trigger into the database I would think.

Comment: You have a ManyToOne relation if you use "inversedBy" on that relation and create the add and remove methods on the Organization entity you can just count the number of users in the organization no need for a preUpdate

Comment: Yes but I do not want to count every single time, I just want to keep a easy track of the number of members, that is why I have an additional parameter.